# Is my question (#128641) likely to help any future visitors?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions, specific-question

I was concerned about my progress in XCOM so I wrote up [a little question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/128641/5398) to find out how difficult the curve is at the beginning of the game.

I got a ton of helpful feedback, but with [each](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/128641/is-the-xcom-project-supposed-to-be-constantly-broke-or-am-i-just-bad-at-finance?noredirect=1#comment175506_128641) [comment](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/128641/is-the-xcom-project-supposed-to-be-constantly-broke-or-am-i-just-bad-at-finance?noredirect=1#comment175503_128641), the question became more and more specific, and less and less applicable in the general case.

[This answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/128643/5398) might have saved it, but it also might have turned it into a dupe of [this](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/89240/5398).

**Is my question likely to help any future visitors?**  If not, I'll delete it.

Comment: The build order part is a straight up dupe. But your question also seems to be kind of about what to expect financially in the game and how to tell if you're hopelessly behind. I think all your details add context (which some people would yell at you if you didn't have), but the question can be answered just fine generically. In short, I think it's fine.

Answer (score 2):

Overall, I think this is a separate question than the other one you link to, which is why I answered it. Your question was about the economy primarily, even though you asked some other questions along side re build order. The other question is about build orders specifically, which is similar but is not likely to show up when players search for information about the XCOM economy. The topics are certainly linked, but they don't share keywords and do have different focuses so they can be separate questions.

I think one direction you could go to ensure that this is useful to other visitors is to change the answer to ask more about the economy (primary sources of income, what an ideal income is at 1/3 months in, something like that) and less about build orders, which would distinguish it from the other answers. If you do I will improve my answer to reflect the modified question.